# Newly added filter is not coming in sidebar facet

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace

I want to add "Education level"->[dcterms.educationlevel] as sidebar facet and search filter.
I did all things like ->
Add the following code snippet to "discovery.xml"->

```html
<bean id="educationLevel" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoverySearchFilterFacet">
    <property name="indexFieldName" value="educationlevel"/>
    <property name="metadataFields">
        <list>
            <value>dcterms.educationlevel</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="type" value="text"/>
    <property name="sortOrder" value="VALUE"/>
</bean>
```

and also add the following line

```html
  <ref bean="educationLevel" />
```

to the following area (in 'discovery.xml')

```html
<!--The default configuration settings for discovery-->
    <bean id="defaultConfiguration" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfiguration" scope="prototype">
        <!--Which sidebar facets are to be displayed-->
        <property name="sidebarFacets">
            <list>
                <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterType" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterMIMEType" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterLanguage" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterSourceOrganization" />
  <ref bean="typeOfLearningMaterial" />
  <ref bean="difficultyLevel" />
  **<ref bean="educationLevel" />**
            </list>
        </property>
        <!--The search filters which can be used on the discovery search page-->
        <property name="searchFilters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="searchFilterTitle" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterAuthor" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterType" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterSubject" />
                <ref bean="searchFilterIssued" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterMIMEType" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterLanguage" />
  <ref bean="searchFilterSourceOrganization" />
  <ref bean="typeOfLearningMaterial" />
  <ref bean="difficultyLevel" />
  **<ref bean="educationLevel" />**
            </list>
        </property>
```

and also add in the below mentioned area,

```html
    <bean id="homepageConfiguration" class="org.dspace.discovery.configuration.DiscoveryConfiguration" scope="prototype">
```

and also add the line

```html
search.index.15 = educationlevel:dcterms.educationlevel
```

in '[dspace-install]/config/dspace.cfg' file

and also add the line

```html
 <message key="xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.educationlevel">Education Level</message>
```

in the file -> [dspace-install]/webapps/xmlui/i18n/messages.xml

but it's not coming in sidebar facet, please help.

Comment: Have you tried running `index-discovery -b` or `index-discovery -f` after you modified your `discovery.xml`?

Comment: Yes,I did. I did all the same things for Type of Learning Material [dc.type.typeoflearningmaterial], Difficulty Level [dc.format.difficultylevel]. Those are working,but the above said one is not working.

Comment: @euler,   I have run the command -> 'bin/dspace index-discovery -b'     
from the terminal of [dspace-install] directory.

Comment: Make sure that there are actually items that contained that metadata. As a test, try to edit one of your items and add that metadata. It will instantly reflect on your sidebar facets once you view the parent collection home page of that item. If that metadata don't exist in your metadata registry, you have to manually add it first.

Comment: It sounds like you have performed all of the recommended steps.  In order to troubleshoot this change, it might be useful to remove and/or modify some of the existing filters to verify that changes to those filters are taking effect.  Make sure you re-index after deploying your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there are actually items with that metadata. In your comment, you said that other custom sidebar facets that you add works, except `dcterms.educationlevel`. As a test, try to edit one of your items and add that metadata.

> Another important property of Sidebar Facets is that their contents are automatically updated to the context of the page. On collection homepages or community homepages it will include information about the items included in that particular collection or community.

It will also show after a search. If that metadata don't exist in your metadata registry, you have to manually add it first (which I assume you did this already since other metadata that you included were not in the default metadata registry).

Comment: I can detect the error. Actually the metadata field would be -> 'dcterms.educationLevel' , but i were using -> 'dcterms.educationlevel' . There was a spelling mistake,just for that it was not working. Extremely sorry for that.